# Android Recycler View orientation can't be changed to horizontal

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, orientation

Currently I have done the code to implement recyclerview with cards view inside. But when I tried to change the recyclerview's orientation from vertical to horizontal it just doesn't change. Since I put the recyclerview inside a fragment, I don't know if it's because of this. My xml code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal"
    app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"/>
```

I have tried both of these:

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.discover_fragment, container, false);
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

and:

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.discover_fragment, container, false);
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 1, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Comment: Can you clarify what "doesn't change" means? It stays vertical or you get a strange behaviour?

Comment: yes, it stays vertically oriented